# Format exception unhandeled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

MaxFailedAccessAttempts = Int32.Parse(syspref.GetValue(State, "ProcessingFlag", "MaxFailedAccessAttempts"))

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to parse a string value which can't be converted into equivalent int value. e.g.

if you are parsing a string which has **numeric characters**, It will work fine:

```
string _stringToParse = "123";
Int32.Parse(_stringToParse);
```

But if you are parsing a string which has **non-numeric characters**, it will give the 'System.FormatException'

```
string _stringToParse = "123Abc";
Int32.Parse(_stringToParse);
```

You can use `Int32.TryParse()` method. If the string value is parsed it will give you the parsed value, but it will not raise an exception. See the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Comment: But please show your code to get the clear understanding. Thanks!